# How to localize anchor link in ember

Tags: ember.js, localization

How I can localize texts which includes anchor link in ember 1.6?
Here is example of what I need to localize:

```
Go to <a {{bind-attr href="https://www.mypage.com"}} target="_blank">To do some staff</a> and give feedback about your expirience. 
(<a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse">help</a>)
```

I know how to translate signel text, pass params etc ... but I can not do in this way:

- translate `Go to`
- put link
- translate `and give feedback about your expirience.`

because in some other language sentence will have totaly different construct.

So I am wondering if it is possible to translate all at oce and put link inside translation? Or some another approach?

Comment: Please take a look at https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's post answer in detail if someone else find them self in the same situation.

Here is translation entry:

```
myTranslationKey: 'Please email us a {{email}} or call us on +111222333.'
```

Setup variable in the controller:

```
init: function () {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);

    var emailLink = '<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com?Subject=Message%20del%20subject" target="_top">foo@bar.com</a>';
    var emailHtmlSafe = Ember.String.htmlSafe(emailLink);
    var translatedValue = I18n.t('myTranslationKey', {email: emailHtmlSafe});

    this.set('translatedValue', translatedValue);
},
```

then in the template put:

`{{{translatedValue}}}`

Be aware that you should put 3 x `{`

Answer (score 0):

Prefer to use an addon such as:

- https://github.com/jasonmit/ember-intl
- https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n

Or have a look at [loc method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_loc) for simple needs.

Comment: `ember-intl` is for ember version `1.13+` and I am working with ember `1.6`